# approximating integral from for small change in limits

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

What's the calculus name for this integral approximation?

$$\int \limits_{a-\frac{1}{2}b}^{a+\frac{1}{2}b} f(t)~ dt \approx b~f(a)~~~~~a >> b$$

I found this approximation for an integral as part of a problem in a signals and systems book without an explanation where it came from.

Comment: This is true when $f$ is continuous at $a$. But $a>>b$ seems weird. Even when $a=0$ the above holds for small enough $b$.

Comment: i thought that part was wrong as well... seems like it has more to do with the narrowness of width b....

Answer (score 3):

This uses the fact that the best local linear approximation of a differentiable function $F$ near $x=a$ is
$$\ell(x) = F(a) + F'(a)\cdot(x-a)$$
(in fact, that can be taken as the *definition* of the derivative).

Here, $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\;dt$$
so $F(a) = 0$ and $F'(a) = f(a)$ (by the fundamental theorem of calculus). This means
$$\ell(x) = 0 + f(a)\cdot(x-a) = f(a)\cdot(x-a)$$
and in particular,
$$\int_{a-\frac12b}^{a+\frac12b}f(t)\; dt =\int_a^{a+\frac12b}f(t)\; dt-\int_a^{a-\frac12b}f(t)\; dt$$
$$= F(a+\tfrac12b) - F(a-\tfrac12b)$$
$$\approx \ell(a+\tfrac12b) - \ell(a-\tfrac12b)$$
$$= f(a)\cdot((a+\tfrac12b)-a)-f(a)\cdot((a-\tfrac12b)-a)$$
$$=f(a)\cdot b$$
The condition $a \gg b$ is probably meant to convey that the points $a\pm\tfrac12b$ are "near" $a$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the midpoint rule or rectangle rule.

See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: This should be written in comments.

Comment: @SMM In the contrary, that is the direct answer to the question "What's the calculus name for this integral approximation?"